# Can tricolour LEDs be connected in series?

Tags: led

I'm constructing a LED matrix using tricolour LEDs. I was wondering - will I be able to wire these in series?

I was told to mount the LEDs in series using stripboard, then wire each stripboard in parallel.

Here's the [datasheet](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/01ff/0900766b801ff521.pdf) for the tricolour LEDs.

Answer (score 1):

The LED described would these days more commonly be called a bi-color LED (the term tri-color refers to LED assemblies with red, green, and blue diodes); it does not allow for series connection since the two diodes are wired cathode-to-cathode.  Some other bicolor diodes are wired anode-to-cathode, thus allowing series or reverse-parallel operation, but the one you linked isn't one of them.

Comment: so does that means as long as I can find ones that have a common anode all will be fine?

Comment: @Ageis: No.  There are four possible arrangements for a three-terminal red-green LED: red cathode to green cathode (common cathode), red anode to green anode (common anode), red anode to green cathode, or red cathode to green anode.  Only the latter two will allow series operation; those types are particularly nice if one is trying to drive the LED from a port pin in a 3.3 volt system.  Wire the non-common anode to VDD and the non-common cathode to VSS.  Connect the LED to the port pin via resistor.  Drive the pin high for one color or low for the other.  Float the pin for LED off.

Comment: oh so like these? http://www.rapidonline.com/netalogue/specs/55-0251.pdf. I need to pray rs will let me return 144 leds lol

Comment: are you sure about 'float the pin for LED off' ? With the pin floating, wouldn't both red and green be forward biased, and therefore go on?

Comment: @JustJeff: Most LEDs have a forward voltage of 1.7 volts or more.  Two such diodes in series would have a combined forward voltage of 3.4 volts; a 3.3 volt supply would thus be a little short of what would be required to light them.  Note that with some LEDs there isn't a whole lot of margin; the trick may be better on 3.0 volts that 3.3 volts.

Comment: @supercat It sounds like you're talking about wiring the two LEDs _inside that package_ in series. I feel like the asking is asking about wiring many of these LEDs in series.

Comment: @fizzisist: Rereading the question, you're right. Not sure how I missed that. Depending upon how one arranges and drives one's matrix, one could put two of each color in series by using a mixture of common-anode and common-cathode LEDs. Each pair of rows and columns would operate two pairs of bi-color LEDs with positive rows and negative columns (or vice versa), or four pairs of LEDs if rows and columns could be driven both high and low (or floated). One LED of each pair would be common-anode, and the other common-cathode; the common terminals of the LEDs in each pair would be wired together.